# Is there a zeroth Greek number noun below trias, dyas, monas?

Tags: vocabulary, ancient-greek, numbers

I gave a list number-based nouns borrowed from Greek as an answer to [a question on using numbers as nouns](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/19307/79):
*monas, dyas, trias, tetras, pentas, hexas, heptas, octas, enneas, decas…*
One can conceivably continue the list further with Greek numerals, but how about taking one step back?

Is there a similar word corresponding to the number zero?
Just like the number zero and the empty set and the zero-dimensional vector space are very useful concepts, I can imagine myself, as a mathematician, wanting have a word for a rank zero version of some kind corresponding to monads, dyads, and tetrads.
What I am looking for is something that feels like a natural continuation of the words listed above, not merely a Greek word for nothingness — unless it happens to fit the bill.
A noun ending in *-ăs, -ădĭs* (so as to make the continuation of the pattern clear) when borrowed to Latin would be great.

Neither Greek nor Latin seems to have a classical word for the number zero, so perhaps it should be based on something like "nothing" or "empty" instead.
If *trias* means "a group of three" instead of just "three", I'm looking for something that means "a group with no members" instead of just "nothing".
What is the best option for a continuation of the list down to zero?
Coining a new word is fine, as long as it comes with a justification.

Comment: _Nulla_ and _nihil_ look like good candidates in Latin. [This wp article and section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0#Classical_antiquity) suggests where to look for a Greek name too. Apparently there _could_ have been a classical word for the concept, even if it was just a novel meaning for an already existent word.

Comment: @Rafael Those are good words to start from, but the analogy to the listed words starting at *monas* is far from clear to a reader. Something like _*nullăs_ or _*nihilăs_ would be more recognizable as a continuation of the pattern. If *trias* means "a group of three" instead of "three", I'm looking for something that means "a group with no members" instead of "nothing". Different answers exploring different options would be very welcome; there's room for several takes on this.

Comment: Yes, I know my comment is far from a complete answer. BTW: I was writing something different at first. The fact that zero was adopted in classical times was a complete surprise to me.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I would actually be happy to see that as an answer. It might not be very pretty, but it might still be the best option. Exploring the options, even if the conclusion ends up being "please no", is very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

μηδέν (not even one—for zero) might suggest the deplorable μηδεμονάς?

Horrible... leading to the rabbit hole of οὐδεμονάς, alarming even in suburban Σόλοι... They'd opt for κένωσις there... A lurid nightmare signifying nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In ancient Greek mathematics and in the language itself, zero was not considered a number (https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6072/did-the-ancient-greeks-have-zero-in-their-number-system).

So, while there may be words for e.g. "none," there is no word for the *number* zero analogous to *monas*, *dyas*, etc.